# Connection to server that has constant IP and port

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a socket program with Java and have a host that clients can connect. That host has a constant `ip` and `port` , if it possible n client connect to server with that `ip` and `port`? or do I have to define unique port for each client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect many clients as you like ( ok limited by ephemeral socket range ) to a server, all clients will connect to the port the server opens its socket on.

Each client will get its own port at its end but the sockets will sort all that out for you.

For interest ephemeral socket ranges are here [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)

Answer (score 1):

you should go through some literature to clarify the concepts of ports, ip addresses and how do applications bind to them. The significance of port is that there can be more than one applications running on one machine but all would be listening on different ports.
Let us suppose that we have a machine with ip a.b.c.d and there is an application listening on port w on this machine, if there is another application running on the same machine then it cannot use port w to receive packets.

Any client application that wants to communicate with the application listening on port w on ip a.b.c.d will use the destination ip as a.b.c.d and destination port as w. So the sending ip and port will not matter ( in most of the cases)